# Kali won't start from USB?

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, bootable-media, liveusb

A verified Kali ISO has been dd'd onto a 16GB USB.
Holding down the options key on my mac whilst booting, and choosing EFI, I have had the following problems in this order:

- Kali loads from `Live (amd64)` but the Kali boot menu is small and half obscured in the top left corner
- Kali does not offer a boot menu anymore

What is wrong with my usb drive, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Kali now install completely manually, you have to set it up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet you need to install refined on your mac.

I have Manjaro Linux running on my 2016 macbook pro that im typing this from; and the way i did that was by first installing refined, then booting from the install medium (thumb drive).

Go here to install: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#installsh